# Dealing with 25 16bit integer using avx2

Tags: avx2

Avx2 has 256 bit vector registers ymm0-ymm15, these registers can deal with 4 integer of 64 bit, or 8 integer of 32bit, or 16 integer of 16 bit. So the parallelism of one avx2 instruction is 4, 8 or 16. My question is: if I want to operate integers which are not multiple times of the parallelism, for example: There are 25 integers, each of them is 16 bit, if I load 16 of them into ymm0, how to deal with the rest 9 integer, since they can't fit exactly into one 256 bit vector register.

Comment: There are different techniques that can be used in different cases, such as masked load/store, overlapping part of the last vector with the second-to-last one, "transposing" the problem so the parallelism is across a different axis (working with 16 instances that each consist of 25 integers), which one or ones apply depend on what computation you're doing, so what are you doing?

Comment: It seems that mask load/store only target on 32 bit or 64 bit,  now I am dealing with 648 integers of 16 bit, doing some arithmetic operation  like addition, subtraction, multiplication etc. And I found that the first 640 integers can store into ymm register since they are multiple of 16, and there are 8 integers left, I don't know how to deal with them, as far as I know mask store and mask load __m256i _mm256_maskload_epi64 __m256i _mm256_maskload_epi32, there is no mask store/load for 16 bit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Even though there is no masked load specifically for 16-bit integers, 8 consecutive 16-bit integers are equivalent (in terms of loading or storing them) to 4 32-bit integers or 2 64-bit integers. Though that seems like overkill to me: easier to just use 128-bit SIMD for that part.